# Echo out from MySQL and add color to text

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form to update room status in our school.
The form has status: ready, working, planned and not ready.

My code for the echo in the file is:

```
<?php 

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "angular");
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM c246 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<div class='room_status_info'>";
            echo "<h3 class='room_numer'><b class='status_info'>Romnummer:</b> " . htmlentities($row['roomnumber']) . "</h3>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<p class='room_status'> <b class='status_info'>Status:</b> " . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<p class='time_updated'> <b class='status_info'>Oppdatert:</b> " . htmlentities($row['updated']) . "</p>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<p class='informasjon_rom'> <b class='status_info'>Informasjon:</b> " . htmlentities($row['information']) . "</p>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<p class='updated_by'> <b class='status_info'>Oppdatert av:</b> " . htmlentities($row['updated_by']) . "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
 ?>
```

Now i want to add a color to the status text.
I have a row called: colorcode where i select the color codes from a dropdown when updating the rooms.

The colorcode is in MySQL, but now i wonder. How am i gonna add that colorcode to the status text?

It's here the color should be:

```
echo "<p class='room_status'> <b class='status_info'>Status:</b> " . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>";
```

The text Status is not gonna have color in it, but the text after it. htmlentities($row['status'])

Hope anyone has some answers.

Comment: Where exactly in your SQL the `colorcode` exists?

Comment: where is your color code ? its from database or you have class in style ?

Comment: I have it in my database.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpreted  your question, you want to display a coloured output from the database, with colours you defined previously.

Something like this would do the trick

```
echo "<p class='room_status'> <b class='status_info' style='color: #'. $row['colorcode']: .' >Status:</b> " . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>";
```

Sukhdev Mohan

Comment: The text Status: should not have the color, but only the $row after it.

htmlentities($row['status'])  This should have color, and not: <p class='room_status'> <b class='status_info'>Status:</b>

If you understand :)

Comment: and echo "<p class='room_status' style='color: #'. $row['colorcode']; .'>" . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>";

Comment: Just did what you wrote here, but then i get an error:

:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: Mea culpa it's this echo "<p class='room_status' style='color: #". $row['colorcode'] .";'>" . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>"; 
Your colorcode is a hex value right? If it's not the case adjust the code.

Comment: When i do that code, then The text Status: wont show. Only the htmlentities($row['status']) is showing but now color.

Comment: echo "<p class='room_status' style='color: ". $row['colorcode'] .";'>" . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>";

my colorcode is stored in database as f.eks : #47d147

I have managed to get both Status: and the status tekst to be one color, but i only want the stored data as a color.

Comment: Also tried something like this:

echo "<p class='room_status'><b class='status_info'>Status:</b> <b style='color:" . $row['colorcode']  . htmlentities($row['status']) . ";'></b></b></p>";

Comment: Question colorcode and status are stored in the same table? if not adjust the query to fetch **ALL** the data

Comment: They are stored in the same table.

Comment: Question what does the query return? do a var_dump($row);

Comment: NULL

Thats the only thing it returns

Comment: You are not fetching anything from the database. Review your code, check names and all.

Comment: I can do this:

echo "<p class='room_status' style='color:" . htmlentities($row['colorcode']) . ";'>". "<b class='status_info'>Status:</b>" . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</b></p>";

But then i get both Status: and $row as green.
So the name for colorcode is correct.

Comment: echo "<p><b class='status_info'>Status:</b>";

Comment: echo <p class='room_status' style='color:" . htmlentities($row['colorcode']) . ";'>" . htmlentities($row['status']) . "</p>";

Comment: With the code you posted i get the $row in green, but the text Status: is not showing.

Comment: Dude I literraly copy and paste your code, rearranging it. Look if you're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b class='status_info'>Status:</b>
```

Add this to it:

```
<b class='status_info' style='color: htmlentities($row['colorcode'])'>Status:</b>
```